# Xamarin .aar Binding: Starting an activity from a library class's intent causes NullPointerException on setImageResource

Tags: android, xamarin, binding

I've spent way too long trying to troubleshoot this. This is my first Xamarin app and I could really use some help on this one.

I start an activity from an .aar library from Xamarin Forms:

```
var intent = WPAPIAuthentication.MakeLoginIntent(Android.App.Application.Context.ApplicationContext);
intent.AddFlags(Android.Content.ActivityFlags.NewTask);
Android.App.Application.Context.ApplicationContext.StartActivity(intent);
```

This works and displays the LoginActivity. This activity then starts a second library activity after the user logs in which causes the following:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.fakeurl.MyApp/com.company.android.library.springboard.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(int)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(int)' on a null object reference
    at com.company.android.library.springboard.MainActivity.c(MainActivity.java:303)
    at com.company.android.library.customactivities.MyFolderActivity.C(MyFolderActivity.java:382)
    at com.company.android.library.customactivities.PostLoginMyFolderActivity.onStart(PostLoginMyFolderActivity.java:179)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1334)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7019)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2741)
```

I tested everything in Android Studio and it works as expected.

Comment: Is the library fully bound? Have you tried decompiling it?

Comment: I decompiled and see the ImageView referenced is set in onCreate():
this.t = getSupportActionBar();
if (this.t != null)
{
  actionbar init...
  this.u = ((TextView)this.t.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.wp_actionbar_title));
  this.v = ((ImageView)this.t.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.wp_actionbar_icon));
}

Fully bound? I have several remove-node elements necessary to compile.

Comment: I also suggest your try to [bind .aar again](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/binding-an-aar), if it still throw `NullPointerException`, you can change the `ImageView`'s id `wp_actionbar_icon`, or change your `ImageView` to `TextView` to test it.

Comment: Unfortunately, the .aar is a third party closed-source library so I am unable to modify any code.